# Deleting duplicate answers containing special characters in the survey

Tags: string, macros, sas, sas-macro

Hello I am dealing with the following problem. I have a survey where you were able to mark several answers as well as add your own one. I am trying to get unique answers to be able to count their occurance for example: let's suppose that we have 3 answers: a, b, c. Person nr 1 marked answer a, Person nr 2 marked answer b, c, Person nr 3 marked a, c. I would like to receive the result: "a" was marked 2 times. To do that i'm trying to delete duplicate answers and create a macro-variable that stores those unique answers: a, b, c.

I have already renamed all of the survey questions to v1-v&n_que. where n_que is a macro-variable that keeps information about the number of questions in the survey. I was trying to split all of the answers into a tables (using the previous example i would get a column with the following values): a, b, c, a, c. Then i wanted to sort this data out and remove duplicates. I've tried the following:

```
%macro coll_ans(lib, tab);
    %do _i_ = 1 %to &n_que. %by 1;
            %global betav&_i_.;

            proc sql noprint;
                    select distinct v&_i_. into :betav&_i_. separated by ', '
                            from &lib..&tab.
                                where v&_i_. ^= ' ';
            quit;

            data a&_i_.;
                %do _j_ = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(%quote(&&&betav&_i_.), ',')) %by 1;
                    text = %scan(%quote(&&&betav&_i_), &_j_., ',');
                    output;
                %end;
            run;
    %end;
%mend coll_ans;
```

It's worth mentioning that if somebody picked more than 1 answer, for example a and b, the answers are separated with the comma, that's why i picked this separator, to unify the record.
I have tried almost everything, changing %quote to %bquote, %superq, writing && instead of &&& and i keep getting the following error (first of 40 others):

```
 ERROR: The function NO is unknown, or cannot be accessed.
```

"NO" is one of the answer to the first question in the survey, full answer is: NO (go to the 9th question). It's worth mentioning that the whole survey is in polish but i am using the right encoding so i don't believe it may cause some problems (hopefully).

I will be grateful for all the advice, because I encountered an insurmountable wall

Comment: Please add a few records showing example of the data you have. (Maybe fake data with ID variable and answers like ‘a’, ‘b’, ‘c’ like you describe).  It should be possible to get what you describe by transposing the data to one record per ID-answer, deduplicating, and then running PROC FREQ. You shouldn’t need to split into multiple datasets. You should be able to transpose with a DO loop, rather than needing a macro %DO loop.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing you have a data set like:

```
data have ;
  input id v1 : $8. v2 : $8.;
  cards ;
  1 a   a
  2 b,c b
  3 a,c c
;
```

You can transpose the data set to make it have one record per ID-variable-value.

```
data tran (keep=id VarName Value);
  set have ;
  array vars{*} v1 v2 ;
  do i=1 to dim(vars) ;
    Varname=vname(vars{i}) ;
    do j=1 to countw(vars{i},',') ;  
      Value=scan(vars{i},j,',') ;
      output ;
    end ;
  end ;
run ;
```

The output data set looks like:

```
id    Varname    Value

 1      v1         a
 1      v2         a
 2      v1         b
 2      v1         c
 2      v2         b
 3      v1         a
 3      v1         c
 3      v2         c
```

You can the use PROC FREQ or SQL to get the counts.

```
proc freq data=tran ;
  tables varname*value/missing list ;
run ;
```

Outputs

```
Varname    Value    Frequency
v1         a               2
v1         b               1
v1         c               2
v2         a               1
v2         b               1
v2         c               1
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's would be better if you posted the format in which you receive the survey data as this would dictate the simplest/fastest approach overall.

Also, as a general rule, it's best to get the inputs & outputs right in non-macro SAS code then use macros to optimize the process etc. It's easier to debug that way - even for someone who's being using macros for a long time...  :)

That said, from your Proc SQL code, it appears that:

a. you're receiving the answers in a single delimited text field, such as "a,b,c" or "b,c" or "a,b,z"

```
*** example data;
data work.answers;
    length answer $10.;
    input answer;
    datalines;
    a,b,c
    a
    b
    b,c
    NO
    a,b,z
    n
run;

*** example valid answer entries;
data work.valid;
    length valid $10.;
    input valid;
    datalines;
    a
    b
    c
    NO
    YES
run;
```

b. you want to validate each answer entry and generate counts, like:

```
NO  1   
YES 0   
a   3   
b   4   
c   2
```

Many ways to do this in SAS but for parsing tokenized text data, a de-duplicated lookup table using the hash object is handy. Code below also prints the following to the log for debugging/verification...

```
answer=a,b,c num_answers=3 val=a val=b val=c validated=a,b,c
answer=a num_answers=1 val=a validated=a
answer=b num_answers=1 val=b validated=b
answer=b,c num_answers=2 val=b val=c validated=b,c
answer=NO num_answers=1 val=NO validated=NO
answer=a,b,z num_answers=3 val=a val=b val=z -invalid validated=a,b, validated=a,b,
answer=n num_answers=1 val=n -invalid validated=  validated=
```

Once you've mastered the declaration syntax for the hash object, it's quite logical and relatively fast. And of course you can add validation rules - such as upper case & lower case entries ...

```
*** first, de-duplicate your lookup table. ;
proc sort data=work.valid nodupkey;
by valid;
run;

data _null_;
    length valid $10. answer_count 4. count 4. validated $10.;
    retain count 0;

    *** initialize & load hash object ;
    if _N_ = 1 then do;

        declare hash h(multidata: 'n', ordered: 'y');
        rc = h.defineKey('valid');
        rc = h.defineData('valid','count');
        rc = h.defineDone();        

        do until(eof1);
            set work.valid end=eof1;
            h.add();
        end;

    end;

    *** now process questions/answers;
    do until(eof);

        *** read each answer;       
        set answers end=eof;        
        num_answers=countw(answer);
        putlog answer= num_answers= @;

        *** parse each answer entry;
        validated=answer;
        do i=1 to num_answers;

            val=scan(answer,i);
            putlog val= @;

            *** (optional) keep track of total #answers: valid + invalid;
            answer_count+1;

            *** check answer entry in lookup table;
            rc= h.find(key:val);

            *** if entry NOT in lookup table, remove from validated answer;
            if rc ne 0 then do;
                putlog "-invalid " @;
                validated=tranwrd(validated,trim(val),' ');
            end;

            *** if answer found, increment counter in lookup table;
            else do;
                count+1;
                h.replace();
            end;

        end;    
        putlog validated=;

    end;

    *** save table of answer counts to disk;
    if eof then h.output(dataset: 'work.counts');

run;
```